# Looking for doubles words

Tags: perl

I'm going to have to write (for an exercise) a perl program which checks a text file for words that are the same, then prints them to a new file (without the doubles).

Could someone help me please. I understand that using a m// function I can look for words, but how do I look for words that I may not know are there? Ex: If the text file has :

*Hello, Hello, how are you?*  I may wish to copy this file to a new one **without** one of the 'Hello'. Of course, I won't know if there are any repeated words in the file ... that's the idea of the program to search out repeated words.

I have a basic script which sorts the words out alphabetically, but step 2 of finding the repeated words ... I can't figure out. Here's the script (hope it's correct so far) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my $source = shift(@ARGV);
my $cible = shift(@ARGV);

open (SOURCE, '<', $source) or die ("Can't open $source\n");
open (CIBLE, '>', $cible) or die ("Can't open $cible\n");

my @lignes = <SOURCE>;
my @lignes_sorted = sort (@lignes);

print CIBLE @lignes_sorted;

chomp @lignes;
chomp @lignes_sorted;

print "Original text : @lignes\n";

sleep (1);

print "Sorted text : @lignes_sorted\n"; 

close(SOURCE);
close (CIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks Kamituel, I was just editing it again so that the script was correct. Read the instructions too late (after posting).

Comment: When you `die`, include the error message: `$!`: `die ("Can't open $source: $!\n");`

Comment: Hi Andy, could you explain why I have to replace 'or die' with '$!:die'? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, what I was saying is that you should put the special `$!` variable in your message.  `$!` is the special Perl variable that describes what the error causing a file failure was.  Change the `die` call to `die( "Can't open $source: $!" );`  So instead of getting back "Can't open foo.txt" it will say "Can't open foo.txt: No such file or directory" or whatever the reason might be for not being able to open the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $source = shift(@ARGV);
my $cible = shift(@ARGV);

open (SOURCE, '<', $source) or die ("Can't open $source\n");
open (CIBLE, '>', $cible) or die ("Can't open $cible\n");

my @input = sort <SOURCE>;
my %words = ();
foreach (@input) {
    foreach my $word (split(/\s/)) {
        print CIBLE $word." " unless ( exists $words{$word} );
        $words{$word} = 1;
    }
}

close(SOURCE);
close (CIBLE);
```

Basic idea is to split the whole text into single words (using `split` function) and then build a hash with this words as a key. When reading next words, just check if this word is already in the hash. If it is - it's a duplicate.

For the string `Hello, Hello, how are you?` it prints: `Hello, how are you?`.

Comment: Great, thanks. My original file was with one word per line - it's a special text. With your code it places the words onto one line. I should investigate how to combine my code with yours. Any suggestions?

Comment: Got it already. I need to add a "\n" on the line - print CIBLE $word."\n" unles ( exists $words{$word}) - Thanks a lot. I need to look up the '.' as i can't remember what that does in the code.

Comment: Another small problem is that the script doesn't sort the words alphabetically as my original script. I'll have to see if I can figure out where to place a sort command?

Comment: Use a temporary array, sort it, and then loop over it. I've updated the answer (note using `foreach` instead of `while`).

Comment: Great thanks.Actually it makes the first version easier to understand now I see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Deduping words from sentences is more complex than it sounds. For example, if splitting the sentences on whitespace, you will get "words" such as `Hello,` which contain non-word characters, and that count as non-duplicate of the real word `Hello`. There are many variables to consider, but assuming the simplest possible case that all characters except whitespace make up legitimate words, you can do this:

```
$ perl -anlwe '@F=grep !$seen{$_}++, @F; print "@F";' hello.txt
Hello, how are you?
yada Yada this is test material dupe Dupe

$ cat hello.txt
Hello, Hello, how are you?
yada Yada this is test material dupe dupe Dupe
```

As you can see, it does not consider `yada` and `Yada` duplicates. Nor would it consider `Hello` a duplicate of `Hello,`. You can tweak this by adding uses of `lc` or `uc` to remove case dependency, and allow for different delimiters than just whitespace.

What we are doing here is using a hash `%seen` to keep track of words that have appeared before. The basic program is:

```
while (<>) {         # reading input file or stdin
    @F = split;      # splitting $_ on whitespace by default
    @F = grep !$seen{$_}++, @F;   # remove duplicates
    print "@F";      # print array elements space-separated 
}
```

The functionality of `!$seen{$_}++` is that the first time a new key is entered, the expression will return true, and all other times false. How does it work? These are the different steps that take place:

```
$seen{$_}     # value for key $_ is fetched
$seen{$_}++   # value for key $_ is incremented, undef -> 1
              # $foo++ returns the value *before* it is incremented, 
              # so it returns undef
!$seen{$_}++  # this is now "! undef", meaning "not false", as in true.
```

For values of 1 and above, which are all true, the `not` operator negates them all to false.

Comment: Great thanks. It's a little more complex than I'm used to, but I'm going to look it over.

Comment: I've been looking at the 'while' solution that you propose but I'm not sure I understand where to place it in my script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about finding duplicate words with different capitalisation then you can do this with a single substitution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($source, $cible) = @ARGV;

my $data;
{
    open ($source_fh, '<', $source) or die ("Can't open $source\n");
    local $/;
    $data = <$source_fh>;
}

$data =~ s/\b(\w+)\W+(?=\1\b)//g;

open (my $cible_fh, '>', $cible) or die ("Can't open $cible\n");
print $cible_fh $data;
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know how to do it in Perl but can easily do it using sed and a couple fo Unix utilities.  The algorithm will be:

1. Separate all words by replacing the spaces by a newline character
2. Sort the words
3. Send the list of sorted words through uniq with -c option (count of words)
4. Delete all words that give you a single occurrence (count of 1 in first column)

The command will go as (replace \t by TAB and \n by ENTER)

```
sed 's/[ \t,.][ \t,.]*/\n/g' filename | sort | uniq -c | sed '/^  *\<1\>/d'
```

Hope that helps.